# Primary directory Audio not allowed for content://media/external/file; allowed directories are [Download, Documents] - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-11, android-storage

I Need a download a audio files from server its working still 29 , and i changed the code for 30 above am facing this issue. I checked here but not found the answer.

Here is my code snippets

```
               File destination = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + File.separator,  urltoDownload.getName());
final String  relativeLocation = getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + File.separator + urltoDownload.getName();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, urltoDownload.getName());
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, urltoDownload.getName());
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
            values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Audio/" + relativeLocation); 
            Uri uri = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"), values);

 ParcelFileDescriptor descriptor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri,"w"); //"w" specify's write mode
            FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = descriptor.getFileDescriptor();

            InputStream dataInputStream = getApplicationContext().openFileInput(destination.getPath());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileDescriptor);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buf)) > 0)
            {
                output.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            dataInputStream.close();
            output.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt .RELATIVE_PATH or do not use MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"). Do not take the .Files. one. There are better suited.